# A button remains in pressed state after being clicked

Tags: html, css, less, frontend, web-frontend

I'm developing reusable buttons. The problem I've faced with is that button doesn't get its original style after being clicked. Here is a snapshot from the LESS file:

```
.some-company-primary-button {
  .material;

  color: @some-company-primary-button-text-color;
  background: @some-company-primary-button-color;

  &:hover,
  &:focus,
  &:active,
  &.focus,
  &.active {
    color: @some-company-primary-button-text-color;
    background: @some-company-primary-button-hover-color;
  }
}
```

Thank you for any ideas!

**EDIT** I'm using it with Bootstrap `btn` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean "doesn't get its original style until something else is clicked":

Change the `:focus` rule.

Clicking on a control will give it the focus until something else move the focus somewhere else.

Comment: I'll try it. But what is the difference for styling between `hover` and `focus` then? As I see in Bootstrap sources they also use `focus` event.

Comment: tnx, I will take a look. but I meant smth like an opinion of a mature frontend guy:)

Comment: The differences between them are not a matter of opinion.

Comment: well, opinion is not an appropriate word, tnx anyway